# How can I create index on CosmosDb for a single element of key-value pair array

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I use Azure CosmosDb with MongoDb Api and got collection of documents with a structure bellow.
I have to filter documents by parameter, ex.

```
x => x.Parameters.Any(xx => xx.Key == ParameterNames.ShiftId && (int)xx.Value == shiftId)
```

It seems to me to better performance I need to create index, but I cannot find any information how can I do it.

```
{
"_id": "08d8c696-2b7b-f227-d5dd-0647a8d51c1c",
"State": 2,
"Created": {
    "$date": "2021-02-01T09:45:54.986Z"
},
"TailId": "e8fb236e-4d48-417b-bf5a-73f1d48fe239",
"Parameters": [{
    "k": "ShiftId",
    "v": 181
}, {
    "k": "Id",
    "v": "147814878155"
}, ....
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Cosmos DB Mongo API, you could try adding a wildcard index on `Parameters` as described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing#indexing-for-mongodb-server-version-36-and-higher).

If you are in a position to change your model, you'll likely have better performance by refactoring the Parameters array into properties closer to the document root. For example:

```
{
  "_id": "08d8c696-2b7b-f227-d5dd-0647a8d51c1c",
  "State": 2,
  ...
  "ShiftId": 181,
}
```

or

```
{
  "_id": "08d8c696-2b7b-f227-d5dd-0647a8d51c1c",
  "State": 2,
  ...
  Parameters: {
    "ShiftId": 181,
    "Id": "147814878155" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it is the best solution to change schema. 
More over, CosmosDB automatically indexes all properties only for Sql API, "Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB automatically indexes the _id field only".

Comment: Ah, I missed that about the Mongo API. Updated to suggest a wildcard policy.